# Does adding a project as a dependency removes the requirement of adding an assembly to the list of references of that project uses?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependencies

I am using VS 2010, and it I am using ProjectA's DLL in ProjectB, and add ProjectA as a dependency to ProjectB, would I need to add ProjectA's DLL to ProjectB's references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you add a project as a reference you will find the project's output (Project's A dll in your example) already referenced in project B. There is no need to do anything else.